Cannot establish HTTP connection with VPS although ufw is allowing outside traffic
Here is the output of sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8090/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8090                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8090/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8090 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)  

Here is the output of http -vv GET http://216.10.242.221 from inside the server, I am using httpie client.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 216.10.242.221
User-Agent: HTTPie/1.0.3



HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 239
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2024 14:47:56 GMT
Location: /static/htmlcov/index.html
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to the target URL: <a href="/static/htmlcov/index.html">/static/htmlcov/index.html</a>. If not, click the link.


The above output means that my HTTP server is correctly "up and running".
But if I run the above same command from outside of my server Then I am getting timeout error.
I can ping my server successfully, I can also login my server through ssh successfully.
My VPS's Ubuntu version is 20.04.6 LTS, here is the output of lsb_release -a command:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal


When I look at tcpdump: sudo tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 by using this command and then request from out side then I can see the packets are hitting the server but I don't know why server is not responding in return.

Please Help me why my server isn't responding from outside, I have no clue where to look for.
